# Postgres Dblink Module failing while doing create extension

Tags: postgresql

When i try to create the DBLink i am getting the error

> /usr/pgsql-11/share/extension/dblink.control": No such file or directory

I have relevant modules installed which are available in `/usr/share/pgsql/extension/`

I've updated postgres from 9.6 to 11 recently so not sure if the migation broke reference extension location